# "PERMISSION_DENIED" when creating course with "courseState": "ACTIVE"?

Tags: google-classroom

I am trying to create a course that's state is ACTIVE.
When i request with OAuth 2.0 like so:

```
{
 "name": "New Course",
 "ownerId": "me",
 "courseState": "ACTIVE"
}
```

I get this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "@CourseStateDenied This user cannot create or transition courses into the requested state.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
 }
}
```

How can I get it to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the domain's settings for creating courses? Is the user a verified teacher?

Comment: * Who can create classes? Anyone in this domain. The user is a verified teacher, i can retrieve the list of courses that he teaches using the same account. I can create courses with the PROVISIONED state but with Active state i get the error above.